# Do unitarily equivalent operators have the same spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

First, some definitions:

> We say that two bounded operators on Hilbert spaces $T:H_1\to H_1$ and $S:H_2\to H_2$ are unitarily equivalent if there is an unitary operator $U:H_1\to H_2$ such that $T=U^*SU$ (where the supscribed $*$ represent the Hilbert adjoint).

I'd already proved the following fact:

> If $T$ and $S$ are unitarily equivalent self-adjoint operators, then they have the same spectrum.

Now... what if they are not self-adjoint? I was looking for some sufficient conditions (such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783450/normal-operators-are-unitarily-equivalent-iff-they-have-the-same-spectrum)) and, more important, **counterexamples**: two unitarily equivalent operators that don't share the same spectrum.

I tried to look for some simple examples (finite ranked and even compact infinite ranked), but had no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
         (U^*SU-\lambda I)= U^*(S-\lambda I)U
$$
So $S-\lambda I$ is invertible iff $U^*SU-\lambda I$ is invertible, which leaves $\sigma(S)=\sigma(U^*SU)$.

Comment: Now I noticed that, yesterday, I didn't used self-adjointness in my proof. This is what 16 hours of study can do to your brain...

Comment: @Filburt : Only 16 hours! Novice. :)